# How do I include a rule set with ModSecurity on IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net, mod-security

I'm using [ModSecurity](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2012/07/announcing-the-availability-of-modsecurity-extension-for-iis.html) 2.7.1 on IIS 7.5 / Windows 2008 R2.
I've reference my base set up conf file in my Web.Staging.config of a site like so:

```
<ModSecurity enabled="true" configFile="*******\ModSecurity.conf" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
```

How do I include another rule set, e.g. the OWASP rule set?

Comment: Can't you just add new rules to the existing conf file?

Comment: Yes I did that as a temporary solution, but the documentation recommends not to do this (in case of future updates), so I wanted to know how to do this the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been playing with Modsecurity 2.7.1 in IIS and i achieved this by using **Include "c:/yourpath/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf"** in your base conf file and also using an Include to pull in the base_rules inside the modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf file.

Just a warning though, iv'e found the ModSecurity/IIS to be very flaky, especially using the OWASP rule set. It has killed my AppPool a number of times.

Also, I have had the [same issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/456900/does-modsecurity-2-7-1-work-with-asp-net-mvc-3) as you where SecRequestBodyAccess prevents ASP.NET from receiving the POST data. I am not using MVC though so i suspect it's not related specifically to MVC.